# service not returning value

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angularjs-factory

I have been working to write a service to return username.

```
var username, $promise;

angular.module('TestApp').factory('UserService', function($http) {
$promise= $http.get('/api/getuser')
.success(function(data) {
  username = data;
});

$promise.then(function() {
return username;
});
});
```

But injecting this service in an controller would return in an undefined value

```
angular.module('TestApp')
.controller('UserLoginController', function($scope, UserService){
console.log("Username is: "+ UserService);
});
```

I have confirmed that http get request returns valid username value. I am quite new to angular and would really appreciate if anyone can point out what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: The root of the problem is that your UserService factory function does not return anything; and therefore I suspect that the UserService factory in the controller will be undefined.  But, I don't have time to attempt to rewrite your code.

Comment: @JeffryHouser: Okay. Thanks for taking a stab at it. I really doubt the way I am injecting it to the controller.

Comment: I suggest you go through the phonecat tutorial on angular website before asking any question.You obviously didnt get the basics of angularjs.If your factory doesnt return anything it's not a factory.

Comment: @mpm: Thanks. I did went through the tutorials and they were helpful. I got a better understanding by watching tutorials from egghead.io. They were awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code above looks like spaghetti. Here is a basic factory that should do what you want:

```
app.factory('UserService', [ '$http', function($http){

   var userService = {};

   userService.getUser = function(){
     return $http.get('/api/getuser').then(function(res){
       return res.data;
     },function(error){
       console.log(error);
       return [];
     });
   }

   return userService;
}]);
```

then call it in a controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'UserService', function($scope,UserService){

  $scope.user = {};
  UserService.getUser().then(function(data){
    $scope.user = data.users[0];
  });
}]);
```

This assumes a json format similar to `{ users: [{ id: "34534534",name: "John" }] }` returned by your API.

Please note that I wrote this on the fly and didn't try it out. It should work though.

Warning: I just edited my code to fix some mistakes.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out. Also, I know its bad code but spaghetti??

Comment: +1; I Was moving to an answer something like this but gave up due to other time constraints.